# Return a file-stream, the server hasn´t finished downloading yet

Tags: php, laravel, file-upload, download

The given scenario is:
I have a service called 'cache' which purpose is to cache file-resources from various systems. By that the direct application-contact is independent from the externals services stability.

The bad side is, users have to wait longer until they get their files, because first the server has to finish the caching. Only after that the files are delivered.

Is it possible to allow users to start downloading a file that is not completed yet, by pointing on the growing file, while another process handles the external files download .

At the moment the file is delivered by using laravels download-response:

```
$file_path = storage_path("app/download_cache/" . $this->id . ".zip");

return response()->download($file_path, $custom_file_name);
```

The caching uses the GuzzleHttp-Client with the 'sink' method to prevent memory overflows at huge files ( some gigabytes):

```
$client->request("GET", $downloadResource->resource_url,
                [
                    'headers' => $headers,
                    'sink'    => storage_path("app/download_cache/.tmp/" . $this->id . '/' . $downloadResource->id),
                ]);
```

(The paths don´t fit together in the meantime some processes work with the files.)

First i just want to ask if someone had a similar problem and maybe an answer/ the knowledge to determine it is possible or not.

Comment: Have you tried serving your guzzle sink file? I don't think guzzle creates any read locks, so as long as it's caching bytes faster than your users are requesting them you might be ok here. I don't know how it would perform in the real world, so you'd have to try

Comment: thank you! will try this, because im interested, but i think its just to vague for 'real' systems. maybe im wrong, but it feels quite hacky :D